# Use Linq query to count grandchild elements that match conditions

Tags: c#, lambda, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

I am trying to determine if the current user has voted on a `ProjectDoc`. This query gives me a value of 1. There is no value in the `ProjectDocVote` table that matches the `UserID`. The `ViewBag.CurrentUserID` value is correct.

```
 var count = Model.Project.ProjectDoc
       .Where(a => a.Current == true && a.DocType == "Cover")
       .Select(v => v.ProjectDocVote
              .SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserID == ViewBag.CurrentUserID)
       )
       .Count();
```

How do I fix this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var count = Model.Project.ProjectDoc
   .Where(a => a.Current == true 
            && a.DocType == "Cover"
            && a.ProjectDocVote.Any(v => v.UserID == ViewBag.CurrentUserID))
   .Count():
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace the `Select` and the `SingleOrDefault` with `Any`:

```
var hasVoted = Model.Project.ProjectDoc
                    .Where(a => a.Current == true && a.DocType == "Cover")
                    .Any(v => v.ProjectDocVote
                               .Any(u => u.UserID == ViewBag.CurrentUserID));
```

Comment: This was helpful, but I'm not sure how to get a count out of it since I can't add Count() to the end?

Comment: According to your question, you don't want a count: "I am trying to determine if the current user has voted on a ProjectDoc". But you can easily change to outer `Any` to `Count`, if you want to know how many votes the user has cast.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, and you're right, I was just using an if statement to see if the count was > 0 to see if it existed. (That could be bad practice, I'm not sure.)

Comment: @JedGrant: Yes, using `Count` is indeed bad practice if all you want is `Any`. The difference is that `Any` will stop enumerating the list as soon as it finds the first item matching the condition while `Count` will always enumerate the whole list.

Comment: Yikes, so if all I am after is to find out if it is null or not then "Any" still sounds like a better choice? Or is that still a bad idea?